# Django and file permissions problems

Tags: python, django, macos

I installed `Django 1.5.4` on my `MAC OSX 10.6.8`. I created a test project.
And I am unable to edit any of those files, it says read only. I can `sudo` it and do the modifications.
But what are the other files it may try to access during run time, if they are read only then my application is not working, for example: `sqlite` database file `"storage.db"`. Can I change the file permissions on the project root folder level and have it applied all the files inside?

Even If could do that, why Django starting project like this? I tried Virtualenv as well, but of no use same thing happens

Comment: Did you `sudo` when running `$ django-admin.py startproject` ?

Comment: yes I did sudo when I ran that command

Comment: You'll want to un-do that and create the project under your user account.

Comment: Brandon thank you, but I created the project under my user account only ..

Comment: Thanks for who voted this down,not sure why they did so. I figured out the problem. Its the way I installed django in my system. Previously I used sudo easy_install , but this time I created a virtual env and installed  django with pip and it worked well.

Comment: Installing as sudo will definitely give you problems. I'm glad you got everything figured out.

Comment: @Krish I up-voted question, Please add an answer instead comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. Its the way I installed django in my system. Previously I used sudo easy_install , but this time I created a virtual env and installed django with pip and it worked well. Virtual environment is the best solution for package installation in python. It wont mess with system packages.